# Fetch required data from API

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

So, maybe this is just me who neither has any experience with Flutter nor asynchronous API calls.

I have an API which provides with a temporary key needed for further requests. And later on I need to fetch data from this api.

I have written the following class to handle the authentification:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<AuthToken> fetchToken() async {
  final response =
  await http.get('https://www.???.net/api/auth?'
      'app_id=redacted&'
      'access_key=redacted&'
      'secret=redacted');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return AuthToken.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load key');
  }
}

class AuthToken {
  final String authToken;

  AuthToken({this.authToken});

  factory AuthToken.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return AuthToken(
      authToken: json['data']['access_token'],
    );
  }
}
```

The thing I don't understand now is, how I would go about fetching further data from the API. I could write another similiar class, calling the fetchToken() before grabbing data. But I do not really understand, how this would work considering the nature of Futures.

A code example would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make a class ApiService that holds all the request method, then make a class DataRepository that holds the authToken that depends on the ApiService

```
class ApiService{
  Future<AuthToken> fetchToken() async {
    final response =
    await http.get('https://www.???.net/api/auth?'
        'app_id=redacted&'
        'access_key=redacted&'
        'secret=redacted');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      return AuthToken.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load key');
    }
  }

  Future fetchSomething({@required AuthToken authToken}) async {
    final response = ....
    // Unauthorized
    if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      throw response;
    }
  }

  Future fetchMoreThing({@required AuthToken authToken}) async {
    final response = ....
    // Unauthorized
    if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      throw response;
    }
  }
}

class DataRepository{
  final ApiService apiService;
  DataRepository({@required this.apiService});

  AuthToken _authToken;

  Future callSomething() async {
    try {
      if (_authToken == null) {
        _authToken = await apiService.fetchToken();
      }
      return await apiService.fetchSomething(
          authToken: _authToken
      );
    } on Response catch (e) {
      if (e.statusCode == 401) {
        _authToken = await apiService.fetchToken();
        return await apiService.callSomething(
            authToken: _authToken
        );
      }
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future callMoreThing() async {
    try {
      if (_authToken == null) {
        _authToken= await apiService.fetchToken();
      }
      return await apiService.fetchMoreThing(
          authToken: _authToken
      );
    } on Response catch (e) {
      if (e.statusCode == 401) {
        _authToken = await apiService.fetchToken();
        return await apiService.fetchMoreThing(
            authToken: _authToken
        );
      }
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```